# 301 redirections in the .htaccess file, on an Apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like **to add two 301 redirections in the .htaccess file**, on an Apache server

1-**One 301 redirection would be** :

```
www.example.com/string1?fixed_text=anystringp=2
```

to :

```
www.example.com/string1?p=2
```

In other words, the following must be deleted from the url :

```
fixed_text=anystring
```

2- **The other 301 redirection would be** :

```
www.example.com/string1?fixed_text=anystring
```

to :

```
www.example.com/string1
```

In other words, the following must be deleted from the url :

```
?fixed_text=anystring
```

3-
where s**tring1 and anystring are variable alphanumeric strings**, 
strings may include :

```
A to Z
a to z
0 to 9
/
.
-
&
```

string1 and anystring may have up to 200 characters

and where **fixed_text is a fixed text (invariable text)**.

I thank you very much in advance for any help in this matter.

Patrick

Comment: Why don't you just ignore the `fixed_text` parameter in your web application?

Comment: My goal is to redirect old urls to new urls. Therefore, I woull like to use 301 redirections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to strip `fixed_text=...` from the beginning of the query string, you must capture the part after it in a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `QUERY_STRING`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fixed_text=.*?(&(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%2 [L,R]
```

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.
When everything works as expected, you may change the flag from `R` to `R=301`.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect from

`/string1/?fixed_text=foobar`

to

`www.example.com/string1`

You can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?fixed_text=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

Or :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fixed_text=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much to Olaf Dietsche and starkeen. I added the solution given by Olaf and it works like a charm. Patrick